# how can I get Google adsense approval?

Tags: node.js, adsense

I have pasted google adsense code on my website pakapoo.in . But google after reviewing said 'code not found'.I have pasted again , but same result. While viewing source code I can see the code there. But google says they cant find the code. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Paste the code in the head tag of your website

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.